# Why does Linq.Enumerable.Where break my ObservableCollection

Tags: wpf, linq, ienumerable, observablecollection, ieditableobject

**Background:**

I am writing a WPF application, strictly following the MVVM pattern. I have a BaseRepository class as a generic interface for connecting to different databases (EF is not an option), and everything works fine; this is just a technical question.

I use a wrapped ObservableCollection called NotifyingCollection, to subscribe to IEditableObject's ItemEndEdit events (my ViewModelBase entity wrapper implements INotifyPropertyChanged and IEditableObject members).

The provided code sample throws an "*'EditItem' is not allowed for this view*" exception when the ReadAll method is called upon editing an item in my WPF DataGrid. **However**, if I replace the line in the method with the commented out part, it works perfectly!

**Question:**

In other words, it looks like relaying the Linq.Enumerable.Where extension method instead of returning an IEnumerable version of the collection removes functionality from the custom collection; why would that happen if they are both IEnumerable?

**Code Sample:**

```
namespace MyCompany.Common.Abstracts
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.Specialized;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data.Common;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Linq.Expressions;
    using MyCompany.Common.Extensions;
    using MyCompany.Common.Utilities;


    public abstract class BaseRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity : ViewModelBase
    {
        protected BaseRepository()
        {
            this.EntitySet = new NotifyingCollection<TEntity>();
            this.EntitySet.ItemEndEdit += new ViewModelBase.ItemEndEditEventHandler(ItemEndEdit);
            this.EntitySet.CollectionChanged += new NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(CollectionChanged);
        }

        protected abstract NotifyingCollection<TEntity> EntitySet { get; set; }

        protected virtual void PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Modify '{0}'", e.PropertyName), "PropertyChanged");
        }

        protected virtual void ItemEndEdit(IEditableObject sender)
        {
            this.Update(sender as TEntity);
        }

        protected virtual void CollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var collection = (e.Action == NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove) ?
                e.OldItems : e.NewItems;

            foreach (TEntity entity in collection)
            {
                switch (e.Action)
                {
                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                        entity.PropertyChanged += this.PropertyChanged;
                        this.Create(entity);
                        break;

                    case NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                        entity.PropertyChanged -= this.PropertyChanged;
                        this.Delete(entity);
                        break;

                    default:
                        Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} '{1}'", e.Action.ToString(), entity.DisplayName), "CollectionChanged");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        public virtual bool Create(TEntity entity)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Create '{0}'", entity.DisplayName), "CollectionChanged");
            return true;
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Read(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
        {
            return this.EntitySet.Where(filter.Compile());
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> ReadAll()
        {
            return this.Read(x => true);
            //return this.EntitySet;
        }

        public virtual bool Update(TEntity entity)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Update '{0}'", entity.DisplayName), "ItemEndEdit");
            return true;
        }

        public virtual bool Delete(TEntity entity)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("Delete '{0}'", entity.DisplayName), "CollectionChanged");
            return true;
        }

        public virtual IEnumerable<TColumn> GetColumn<TColumn>(string columnName)
        {
            var lookupTable = this.Read(x => x != null);

            List<TColumn> column = new List<TColumn>();
            foreach (TEntity record in lookupTable)
            {
                column.Add(record.GetPropValue<TColumn>(columnName));
            }
            var result = column.Distinct();

            foreach (TColumn element in result)
            {
                yield return element;
            }
        }

        public abstract int Commit();

        public abstract DbTransaction BeginTransaction();

        public abstract void Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From MichaelLPerry's blog: [Common mistakes while using ObservableCollection](http://updatecontrols.net/doc/tips/common_mistakes_observablecollection)

> ObservableCollection is imperative. Linq is declarative. The two
>   cannot be used together without extra help.
>
> Imperative code explicitly acts upon something. When using an
>   ObservableCollection, you explicitly call Add, Remove, and other
>   methods to change the collection. You have to decide exactly when and
>   how to take these actions.
>
> Declarative code implicitly generates something. When using linq, you
>   declare what a collection will look like, how it will be filtered,
>   mapped, and transformed. You don’t explicitly modify the collection.
>
> These two paradigms don’t mix. Once you use linq on an
>   ObservableCollection, it is no longer observable. There are
>   open-source projects like Bindable Linq that bridge the gap. But
>   without that extra help, people are often surprised when things don’t
>   work.

Comment: Couldn't have asked for a better explanation, thanks! Indeed, I suspected it was creating a new collection, and therefore not pointing to the same reference any more.

Answer (score 0):

The reurn value of `EntitySet.Where` method won't be the original `NotifyingCollection<TEntity>` anymore.